# Download older versions of jQuery UI

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

How can I download Oder Versions of jQuery UI ? (Script + Theme (Flick) and images) 

 I want to download 1.8.5 version with Images. I found [this](http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.5/themes/flick/jquery-ui.css) link in google CDN 
but I didn't found anything for images.

Comment: There's a "Legacy" link currently leading to v1.7.3 right on the [jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/download) homepage.

Answer (score 3):

Here are the links you need:

> http://jquery-ui.googlecode.com/files/jquery-ui-themes-1.8.5.zip
>   (contains all the themes)
>   http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.5/jquery-ui.js
>   http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.5/jquery-ui.min.js

Answer (score 2):

For what it's worth, here are all of the older versions
https://code.google.com/p/jquery-ui/downloads/list

Answer (score 0):

Below are some old versions, including one that goes back all the way to version 1.

- https://jqueryui.com/download/all/
- https://github.com/jquery/jquery-ui/tags